# currentUser is returning null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a react app using firebase auth for authentication.

After a person logs in, it redirects them to a books page. Here's the submitLogin handler

```
import { auth, firebase } from "./firebase";
async function googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    await auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(
      async (result) => {
        const token = await auth?.currentUser?.getIdToken(true);
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem("@token", token);
          navigate("/book-list");
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
}
```

Then in the books page, I try getting `currentUser` so that I can call `getIdToken()`, but `currentUser` is returning null.

```
import { auth } from "./firebase";
const currentUser = auth.currentUser
```

Here's the firebase.js file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {...};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
export { auth, firebase };
```

How can I call `currentUser` from another file after a user is signed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Since the books page is a new page, the Firebase SDK will need to restore the authentication state from local storage, where it automatically persists it. This requires it to make a call to the server, to for example check if the account has been disabled. Since we can't block the page load, your main code continues to execute and sees that `currentUser` is null.

What you'll want to do instead is *listen for the authentication state* of the user, as shown in the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

This callback will automatically fire when the user session has been restored, or when that failed, or when there was never a signed in user to begin with, or whenever the auth state changes, and is thus the perfect place to update your application for the latest authentication state.

Comment: Cool! Should that be in  `useEffect`

Comment: @Jessica yes, that's the most likely place to put it in a react app

Comment: Yup, indeed. And then you'd typically store the current user in your state, so that the UI automatically refreshes when the auth state changes..